# Firefox Video will not load

Tags: firefox, video, cdn

I have a cdn based video, but it is not playing on firefox. I have the .htaccess file which is widely used:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/.htaccess

I am aware of firefox interpreting this as an incorrect video type. However it is still not working.

```
Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource http://{video-url}.mp4 failed. neils-imac.local:5757
HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource http://{video-url}.webm failed. neils-imac.local:5757
HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource http://{video-url}.ogv failed. neils-imac.local:5757
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused. neils-imac.local:5757
"Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."
```

Even with the script above, to no avail it does not load. I have the file both on a rackspace CDN and local both have the same bug.

Comment: What does your html look like? It looks like you are not specifying the correct mime types in your source.

Answer (score 2):

According to [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP4_H.264_%28AAC_or_MP3%29) you should use .webm or .ogg for firefox and opera. You can include both formats to make it work on all modern browsers

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if your path isn't correct. If you have your video stored in the `src` folder then do this:

```js
import background from "./assets/background.mp4"; // mine is stored in src/assets

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <video src={background} autoPlay muted loop id="background-video" />
    </>
  );
}
```

else if you have your video in your `Public` folder then your import path will look like this:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* my video is stored in public/assets */}
      <video src="/assets/background.mp4" autoPlay muted loop id="background-video" />
    </>
  );
}
```

(you don't have to write "Public" in the path)